# Changing Length of Siebel Column

Tags: siebel

Suppose we have a existing siebel column and this column has corresponding mapped eim column also. If I change the length of this siebel base table's column from 100 to 200varhcar by running alter query from backend. How it will impact on the EIM process? Will import process be successful?

Regards,
Robin

Comment: Why would want to change column size by doing an alter query on database?
Do it the right way. Change the column length from Siebel Tools adn run the EIM Mapping wizard to synchronize the corresponding EIM tables.
Have you already tried this way ? Is it not working ?

Comment: Sudip Saha - I have not done it and I know the way to do it. I want to understand what would happen if someone does this way (Using alter query). I want to know it for conceptually. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in knowing conceptually, here are the implications that i can foresee.

a) Table column added using alter table is virtually useless as the application wont be able to use it because its definition is missing from Siebel Repository.

b) If you change the length of an existing column, application would still be using the length mentioned in Siebel Repository.

c) EIM process will ignore your new column length as it loads data dictionary before running the job.

d) And finally, during code migration you have to do the alter table every time since DDLSync process cannot take care of your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Sudip Saha for the answer. So if i run the EIM data load on this column whose length I have modified. Will EIM process the data or it will give some error? If it will give some error what it would be?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you not to alter the length of an existing vanilla table column, and instead extend the database table to add a new column. Just as the other poster mentioned, you should do this using Siebel Tools. You will then need to also add reference for this new field into the EIM components (this you also do using Siebel Tools).

This is a best-practice. If your client ever had an Siebel code review done by Oracle, you would be told to do what I described above (not what you were considering doing).

Comment: I have not done it and I know the way to do it. I want to understand what would happen if someone does this way (Using alter query). I want to know it for conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the column length using the alter table command will only change it in the database layer, which will have no repercussions with a siebel standpoint. The EIM tables will still be valid as they will be using the column length mentioned in the repository sent in by tools. If you dont change it in the tools and apply the table, I dont think the changes will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would not  recommend that you do this. In this case, probably nothing will go wrong. EIM columns will load data that are upto 100 characters long but from the gui, you could insert upto 200 characters. Something unexpected can go wrong, we would need to know your application better to answer this question.